# Include/Exclude specific files using wildcards in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I have a directory that contains both an uncompressed and a minified copy of jQuery. Depending on my deployment scenario, I may only want to distribute one or the other. Based on Seva Titov's answer, I have an ItemGroup with the following item:

```
<jQueryFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\js\jquery\*.js"
             Exclude="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\js\jquery\*.min.js" />
```

which will just grab jquery.2.1.1.js and exclude the minified version.

For the opposite, it is even simpler with just:

```
<jQueryFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\js\jquery\*.min.js" />
```

which will only grab the minified version.

But what if I have a scenario where the folder also includes other files to copy like images?

I can generalize copying non-minified files with recursion by using:

```
<jQueryFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\js\jquery\**\*.*"
             Exclude="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\js\jquery\**\*.min.*" />
```

My question now is, how do I achieve the opposite effect and grab all files with ANY extension except plain ".js"? So I might want "jquery\images\foo.png" AND "jquery\jquery.2.1.1.min.js" but I want to exclude the unminified js files.

Comment: You first include won't add them why not just switch on a second condition and then att them

Comment: @ilya-kozhevnikov Any thoughts on this one?

Comment: @maxmoore14 could you show this code in context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to accomplish using `Exclude` attribute for the item group element. E.g.:

```
<jQueryFiles 
    Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\js\jquery\*.js" 
    Exclude="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\js\jquery\*.min.js" />
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks very much. I will definitely mark this as the answer, but I am also going to edit the question slightly to include another scenario.